# How to declare anonymous arraylist in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to declare anonymous arraylist in java so that on the nature of constructor list can be initialize with any type of object. For example:

```
    ArrayList<Anonymous> list;

    public AdapterChatWindow(Activity act, ArrayList<CommentData> list, String extras) {        
        this.act = act;     
        this.list = list;
    }

    public AdapterChatWindow(Activity act, ArrayList<ChatHistory> list) {       
        this.act = act; 
        this.list = list;
    }
```

Is this possible? Any alternate Solution? Is this possible with list type data structure?

Comment: Why don't you try this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by declaring anonymous arraylist. Are you asking about parameters on the constructor? You can use `List<?>` or `Object...`, but you may have to cast the elements. Have a look on generics - this may give you want you are looking for and also has compile-time type safety.

Comment: ArrayList<?> list, this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic type:

```
public class AdapterChatWindow<T>
{
    ArrayList<T> list;

    public AdapterChatWindow(Activity act, ArrayList<T> list, String extras)
// ....
```

Then use it like this:

```
AdapterChatWindow<Foo> acw = new AdapterChatWindow<Foo>(...);
```

Comment: What's the difference between ArrayList<?> list; and ArrayList<T> list; ?

Comment: [Generics tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for generic for example..

```
{List<? extends "your super class"> list;}
```

now you can initialize your list  with any of the subclass of "your super class"

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `ArrayList<Object> list` but you'll have to carefully cast your array items when you want to do anything with them.

Comment: If you are going for `ArrayList<Object> list`, you might as well skip the parametrization: `ArrayList list`

Comment: I think i have found a better answer myself by declaring arraylist like this  ArrayList<?> list; in java. Thanks but for your help